# Adding column to many-to-many auto generated table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many

I have Class and Student objects. Both have collection of another as property. Which automatically creates many to many table. Is there a way to add column to this table which relates to the relationship without creating many-to-many table by myself ?

Comment: Totally valid question, "Is there is a way to add new column to auto generated many-to-many table in nHibernate". I have the same question.

Comment: Are you saying you want to create extra properties on the `many-to-many` table OR you don't want a `many-to-many` table?

Comment: I want to add to many-to-many association table property. how can I do it if this table is generated automatically by Fluent NHibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. You have to promote the association table to an entity and have a one to many association to in on both Class and Student.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, although really @Ricardo is technically correct really you should promote the join table to a fully qualified entity.

Some blogs posts that I have seen where people add extra properties to a many-to-many join  table can be found here:-

1. http://thesoftwaresimpleton.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/nhibernate-many-to-many-with-extra.html
2. http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2010/12/26/many-to-many-relationships-with-properties.aspx
3. http://www.thebuttonfactory.nl/?p=874
4. [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=nhibernate%20many-to-many%20extra%20propertires#hl=en&sa=X&ei=GnXsT9HPGsXu8AOD-om_BQ&ved=0CFcQvwUoAQ&q=nhibernate%20many-to-many%20extra%20properties&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=c33d18147f5082cc&biw=1920&bih=1019) turns up a lot (espically S.O. questions)